# Tools for working with C #ifdef preprocessor directives?

Tags: ide, filetype-c

I want to work with a C code with a lot of #ifdef directives. I wonder if there is a program, that will show me, which of these #ifdef's will be left in the code, and which will be cut out by preprocessor.

Or, maybe, a tool, showing a list of defined preprocessor variables for this exact position in the source.

Comment: Take a look at [sunifdef](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sunifdef/files/sunifdef/).  Not updated in almost 8 years, but the C preprocessor hasn't exactly seen active development since than, either.  It works pretty well in my experience.

Comment: I found a http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideIfDef , which allows hiding unused code. Haven't tested it yet. Should be useful.